# Image links css

Tags: css, image, hyperlink

So, I have two image links who act like tabs. I photoshoped them so they have an invisible background. How can I change the background of the image selected just like a tab?

I have these codes:

```
<div id="menutabs">
    <li><a class="tabbuttons" href="menuinicial.html"><img src="summary.png" alt="" width="70" height="15"></a></li>
    <li><a class="tabbuttons" href="trackit.html"><img src="trackit.png" alt="" width="70" height="15"></a> </li>
    </div>
```

and the css, which is not working, only the hover one. the active attribute is not working, the color doesn't "lock". Maybe it's because it's an image? Hope you can help me!

```
#menutabs li{
    display: inline;
}

.tabbuttons:active{
    background: #ccc;
}

.tabbuttons:hover{
    background: #666;
}
```

Comment: I m not clear with your question... you have two tabs on which clicking them will be switching your backgrounds. Is that that you want to say?

Comment: No No. They are two images links, and the image links are square with black border, some text but the background is transparent. What I wanted is just to change the link background when that link is active. For example, when i click the link "summary" i want the square to have a #ccc background to know that that link is active at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The `active` state is only triggered when an item is clicked, like a hyperlink/button etc but it is removed when the mouse is released.

In short, the active state doesn't do what you want here.

What you'll want to do it add an `'active'` css class to the tab when it's clicked and style that class appropriately with the background image.